# Is there any way to trim YouTube video without downloading it to local machine?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I am creating an app to trim video where a user either can upload the video file or can paste YouTube URL.
I am able to make the trimmer work for upload video using `FFmpeg`, but for YouTube URL, firstly I need to download the video to the local machine and then trim it using `FFmpeg`.

I am using `youtube-dl` NodeJS library to save the video file to locally, but the issue is as I am allowing the user to download only 15Sec video no more than that, and I have applied validation of 60m long video, yet when I get 1080p video there are two issues.

```
1. There is no audio in the 1080p video.
```

and

```
2. The video is taking too long to download locally and the process is taking almost 7-8mins to complete.
```

For the first one, I can get the audio and video separately and then merge both of them in the video, but the second one is where I am stacked.

I have added a time log I can see the trimming is taking only about 3-4 seconds, but the downloading is taking too long.

Is there any way to make it work faster? Or, Is there any way I can download only that part of the video, not the full video, in any technology.

I am open to using any technology until it is working faster than my current implementation.

If this is something related to server configuration, please suggest which one would work better.

Comment: Let Youtube deliver the exact cut video when you have the Youtube-URL? `https://www.youtube.com/embed/p_BXXOKf6uE?start=50&end=55&version=3` will start at 50 second and stop at 55th second.

Comment: There are two reasons, first is I'll need to add iframe instead of HTML video tag. and second, there is a possibility the video is removed from Youtube, but it should not remove from our platform. 

Not sure how [Kapwing](https://www.kapwing.com/studio/editor/trimmer) is doing

Comment: I might not get it: You are creating a second Youtube that (1) full caches videos from Youtube or (2) save videos uploaded and then only serves portions of the video (1) or (2) to the user. In this case for (1) you need to get the full video - what Youtube might not like - but anyway limitation I think is bandwith... so I only can think of speeding up using Servers that might be closer network-hop-/bandwith-wise.
If you can think of only partially caching Youtube-Videos (1) I currently dont see an issue with only loading from Youtube what you exactly need to save time.

Comment: I am developing something like [Kapwing](https://www.kapwing.com/studio/editor) trimmer, where users can enter the Youtube Video URL and select a particular time range and then the video should download and save in the user profile, at the same time system is also allowing users to upload video from their computer.

Comment: Then why dont you fetch `https://www.youtube.com/embed/p_BXXOKf6uE?start=50&end=55&version=3` at backend to directly get what you need (without FFMPEG) and attach the downloaded video to users profile. It doesnt matter if you use Iframe or Video-Tag cause you are providing the copied video from your backend and can decide how to display.

Comment: Yes, you're right. that's what I can do, but the issue is I need to allow users to download the trimmed video from the profile in the coming days, and that's what preventing me to work on your suggestion